# Apps that need access to camera wont work on newest android version

Tags: updates, camera

I recently updated my developer device, a nexus 5, to android 5.1.1, but since doing that any apps that I have written that need access to the camera will no longer work, an error saying cannot access the camera appears instead. The apps worked fine before the update and they work in the emulator with the previous version of 5.1, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Was this an in-place upgrade?  If so, did you reinstall the apps or just try to launch them as-is?

Comment: AFAIK, I don't see any [changes in API](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/22/changes.html) that may break camera usage from API 21 to API 22.